# what's the difference between ant and ant-nodeps?

Tags: java, ant

I am wondering why there are ant and ant-nodeps packages. What's the difference between those two?
Why need both on some system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ant has a bunch of so-called "optional" tasks which depend on various 3rd-party libraries, but which aren't necessary for the core tasks.  The `nodeps` package will contain just Ant itself, whereas the full package will contain Ant as well as the 3rd party libraries necessary to run the optional tasks.

Comment: according to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant-nodeps it's vice versa - "contains all the optional tasks and types which do not have particular dependencies"

Comment: As of `ant 1.8.2` (late 2010), there is no separate `ant-nodeps.jar` anymore, it has been merged into `ant.jar`.